# Pandas: Compare consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have found a few solutions by googling but I was never able to apply those properly and I was running into error which I couldn't fix so I have to ask. I tried to create function and then apply it to the dataframe but run into this error and I can't fix it.

> "'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'shift'"

So, I have this first dataframe

```
    A   B
1   0   0
2   1   0
3   0   0
4   0   0
5   0   1
6   0   0
```

And the result should look like this:

```
    A   B
1   0   0
2   1   0
3   1   0
4   1   0
5   1   1
6   0   0
```

So, when 1 occurs in column A, it should reocur in column A till 1 occurs in column B. No other input is possible and it will be for few thousand rows.

Thank you.

EDIT: [Samplesizedata](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Qz7Rres8IrThkJN1-HUImLj-jkuSLaaz)

EDIT2: This is confirmation that the edited answer works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
df.A = (df.A.cumsum() != df.B.shift().cumsum()\
    .fillna(0, downcast='infer')).astype(int)
```

Description:

- `df.A.cumsum()` produces a sequence of numbers increasing
  on each `1` in `A` column.
- `df.B.shift().cumsum()` produces similiar sequence for column `B`,
  but shifted 1 place down and with `NaN` at the first place.
- `fillna(0, downcast='infer')` replaces the initial `NaN` with `0`
  and changes the type of the whole sequence back to `int`.
- `(... != ...)` computes a boolean vector - almost what you want.
- `astype(int)` converts the above **boolean** vector
  to **int** vector.
- the whole result is substituted to `A` column.

## Edit

After your comment and a longer source data, I decided to solve
the issue completely other way.

Start from defining a function, to be applied to each row:

```
def xx(row):
    global nextRes
    currRes = nextRes   # Set current result from the saved value
    if row.B == 1:
        nextRes = 0                 # Off next
    else:           # B == 0
        if row.A == 0:
            pass                    # No change
        else:       # A == 1
            currRes = nextRes = 1   # On now
    return currRes
```

This function uses a global variable `nextRes` - what should be
the result for the **next** row.

`B == 1` (regardless of `A` value) means "switch off", but starting
from the **next** row.

Otherwise (`B == 0`) we have 2 possibilities:

- `A == 0` - no change,
- `A == 1` - "switch on" **now**.

Then, to perform your task, initialize the "next" value and apply
the above function to each row:

```
nextRes = 0
df.A = df.apply(xx, axis=1)
```

Optionally, to easily compare source data with the result, run instead:

```
df['new_A'] = df.apply(xx, axis=1)
```

This way you will have **both** source data and the "new value" of `A`.

Comment: Your solution worked on sample size but then I tried it on my real data and it doesn't do exactly what I need. Definately my fault by not covering all angles in my question. Would you mind looking at this bigger set? I added my set to the original post. Just to explain: When 1 occurs in B, it should not change A to 1. Also when when 1 occurs in A few times without 1 in B, it should continue with adding 1s. Hopefully it's not too confusing. If yes I can add create another file how it hsould look like. Thanks.

Comment: As I understood your comment and bigger sample data: Case 1: A=1, B=0 -> 1 from the **current** position. Case 2: A=0, B=1 -> 0 from the **next** position.
Case 3: A=0, B=0 -> no change. But what to do if **both** A and B = 1?

Comment: If both 1, then A=0, because any B = 1 kills any streak.